# How to get Selected categories ids by jquery in product add/edit page

Tags: magento2, product, adminhtml

I want to get categories ids from the select box which are selected in the product add/edit time on the admin side by Jquery.

I tried to get value from the hidden box but not able to find a hidden box for selected categories id in product form.

[image]

Comment: Add your code to the question as well which you have tried.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to get a category id from this box by jquery but there is no ID. I did not write code yet. Jquery line $('#categories_id').val() but that field don't have any id

Comment: Atleast first start with the code by checking the events and all

Comment: Let me try first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a **UI component** so we need to get it via **uiRegistry** and then get the value:

```
uiRegistry.get('product_form.product_form.product-details.container_category_ids.category_ids').value();
```

And put '**uiRegistry**' as one of the dependencies of my js file. Below are the full code of my js file

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'uiRegistry'
], function ($,uiRegistry) {
    'use strict';
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
       var category_ids=uiRegistry.get('product_form.product_form.product-details.container_category_ids.category_ids').value();

    });
});
```